# android - adding a marker to a google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am trying to add a marker to a google map fragment.

the next code is for when a user is in a phone interface ane he clicking on a an item, that's inside a listview.

all i want to do to is to replace the list fregment and show the user the location of the place with a marker.

This is the code i have used, for when i want to replace the fragment -

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.camera(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(place, 17));
        options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }


        GoogleMap map = mapFrag.getMap();

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(place);
        markerOptions.title(name);


        marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.phone_cont, mapFrag, "map");
        Log.d(TAG, "AFTER TWO LINES");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

But it seem to make the app crushing, any idea what am i doing wrong over here?

Answer (score 0):

because you are doing all of this

```
GoogleMap map = mapFrag.getMap();

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(place);
    markerOptions.title(name);


    marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

before you even created the map so `mapFrag.getMap()` is null

you need to create the marker after the fragment has been created

Comment: so what i need to do in order to first creating the fragment, and than adding the marker?

Comment: you need to create the fragment, wait for it to get created then you can do what you want with the map. always check to make sure the `getMap()` does not return null, it is does then the fragment has not been created yet

Comment: i have tried to make that the map will be shown and than calling a function to add the marker - but now there's a map, but no marker